# Create all containing windows executable from jlink image

Tags: java, windows, exe, java-11, jlink

I have a functioning jlink image (including a custom jre). It works fine. But for my use case i need to package all files of the jlink image into a single all containing executable (`.exe`).

I was able to generate an all containing `.msi` installer using `jpackage` of OpenJDK 14, which is not bad but not the solution needed.

Is there currently a way to package a jlink image into an windows executable, so that i can just run it without anything else needed?

Comment: If you managed to produce an `msi` with `jpackage`, what happens when you just ask for an `exe` instead of `msi`?

Comment: It stil generates an installer. Because the command used is create-installer.

Comment: I see. So there’s no such tool yet.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some kind of third party option to do smthlike this.

Comment: I suppose, the 3rd party tools that existed prior to the module system get updated for module support, if not already done. Unfortunately, I don’t know of any tool claiming to have support for a self contained runtime image. Usually, their logs say “JDK9+ support” and mean, they do not crash and have support for a module path setting…

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) for creating a .exe file from your image. The generated .exe file works as a wrapper on and is not a single all containing executable, but you can use your jlink image plus this .exe in  [Inno setup](https://jrsoftware.org/) or some other similar tools to create a single .exe installer.
Note that Launch4j needs a jar file to create .exe file. But this jar file is never used and the jar file in the jlink image is used.